# Problems connecting to SQL Server 2000 with Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm writing a program for a commercial company that uses SQL Server 2000 for it's applications.
The problem is that asking them to change to SQL Server 2005/2008 to use with .NET application is very difficult, because they will have to re-write everything. I installed SQL Server 2000 on WinXP with Oracle VirtualBox but other computers do not recognize the server, and cannot even ping to it.
Is there a way to make a virtual-machined computer to be recognized on a local network?

Comment: Please try to answer this question. It is pretty urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Bridged Networking.

Here's a page that goes through the different network options you have in virtualbox.
https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1